# Accept JSON in Spring Boot REST Service with jackson json

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc, jackson

I am mapping RequestBody directly to POJO class in Rest Service.
Spring boot is using default Jackson Http Request Mapper.

Problem is with JSON Object. Jackson does not accept pure json. We need to send JSONString (string in json formate).

Example:

> {
>
> > "name" : "dk",
> >
> > "apps" : "['WHATSAPP','TALK']"
>
> }

And I want to receive json like:

> {
>
> > "name" : "dk",
> >
> > "apps" : ['WHATSAPP','TALK']
>
> }

Is their any way to accept pure JSON in spring boot rest services.

Comment: how your POJO looks like?

Comment: I don't understand your question. There is only one JSON. And it is mostly transferred as text in body of HTTP message.

Comment: JSON you have specified above is not correct. JSON field values should contain `double quotes` e.g. `"apps":["WHATSAPP", "TALK"]`